# bash script to append result next to value in list

Tags: bash, while-loop

So I have a simple bash script that executes a `whois` command of a domain list.

```
list.txt
domain1.com
domian2.com
domain3.net
```

.... (there are more than 200 values)

This returns the Registar URL. In some cases this is null and in some others it returns a real value.
But I would like to know exactly the value and append that next to heach of the values of the list is this possible? Would like the result to be:

```
list.txt
domain1.com godaddy.com
domian2.com godaddy.com
domain3.net NULL
```

This is script but it only returns value and i´m not sure if they match with the array of values in the list. I also did similar with for each but I think while loop is better?
Is there a different way to do it?

```
while read p; do
      whois "$p" | grep 'Registrar URL' | awk '{print $3}' || true
      if [ ! -z "$p" ]
       then
          echo "\$p is empty"
      else
          echo "\$p is NOT empty"
    fi
    
    done < list.txt
```

Comment: That sounds like you want to either `echo "$p"` or `echo "$p $result"`, right?

Comment: BTW, the `|| true` makes it sound like you're using `set -e`. [Don't do that.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't far from the mark.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS= read -r p; do
    result=$(whois "$p" | awk '/Registrar URL/ {print $3}')
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$p" "${result:-NULL}"
done <list.txt
```

- Using the `-r` argument to `read` prevents backslashes in the input from being silently removed.
- Using `awk '/pattern/ { action }'` avoids the need for a separate `grep`.
- Using `var=$(pipeline)` stores the output of your pipeline in a variable so you can operate on its results.
- `${var:-value}` is a [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) that expands to `$var` should the variable be set and non-empty, or to the constant value "value" otherwise.